# find string with regex in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I am new to regex and therefore i gone through php manual for regex and tried the below:

i have a string like this:

`c-1`

`c-10`

`c-100` and so on upto `c-unlimited`

now i want to confirm that the string coming is a valid string which starts with `c-` and after `c-` it only contains numbers..

to get this work i have used `preg_match`

```
$slug='c-12';

if(preg_match("/\[c-(.*?)]/",$slug,$result)){ echo "TRUE";}
else{ echo "FALSE"; }
```

also this:

```
$pattern = '/^c-/';
if(preg_match($pattern, substr($slug,2), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE){ echo "TRUE";}
else{ echo "FALSE"; }
```

and also this:

```
$pattern = '/^c-/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $slug, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3){ echo "TRUE";}
else{ echo "FALSE"; }
```

and one more thing i also wanted to to validate the string from end. like below:

```
 $slug="my-string-content-123";
```

here i wanted to validate that the string contains the number at end after `-`

example `123`

but i am not able to get it work... and i am sorry for my bad english..

any help or suggesstion would be a great help.. thanks in advance..

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion both answers presented are going to yield unexpected results for you.. perhaps it would be good if you better defined what "c" or "my-string-content" can actually be

Comment: there are only two cases.. first `c-` case and second is `any-string-but-number-at-end-like-this-123`

Comment: okay well if "any-string" *really* means *anything* then okay, I guess you're set. so I guess `"*$($#safdsfsf\t\tfoo\t\n     $&^@#\t\n-123"` (\t==tab \n==newline) is good to go, yes?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Sir i am new to regex.. but Alam Do Sir's answer works for me...?

Comment: Yes, @AlmaDo answer will certainly match what you want. But the question I'm  posing is whether or not it may match *more* than you want. For an example, is the string I mentioned above *really* acceptable for you, because AlmaDo's regex will match it.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Sir i just want that the string must contain number at the end after `-` and ignoring the rest string...so is it ok to accept Alma Do answer????

Comment: Sure, if all you care about is that it ends in "-[number]" and you don't care what comes before that, then AlmaDo's answer is fine. Well actually his/her regex does restrict it to not have any numbers. So a better "I don't care what comes before that" would be this for the first arg `'/(.*)-([0-9]+)$/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For common (not just `c-`) case:

```
$slug="my-string-content-123";
if(preg_match('/([^0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$/', $slug, $matches))
{
   //prefix is in $matches[1];
   //the number is in $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/^c-\d+$/",$slug,$result);
```

`^c-` = start with `c-`

`\d+` = 1 or more digits

`$` = end of string

Comment: Sir.. Thank You very much.. works like charm.. when the case is `c-`